# How to implement a button styled tree view in c# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, drawrectangle

I have a tree view in my winform application.I have set its DrawMode property to OwnerDrawAll and used its drawnode event to customize tree nodes as I wanted to show highlighted text when user performs a search.Now, I want to improve it further by making its nodes look like the ones in the screenshot.They look like buttons.But how do I draw a rectangle which look like a button.

[image]

Here is my code to draw node.

```
 private void trwFileExplorer_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs)
 {
    if (e.Node.IsSelected || trwFileExplorer_SelectedNodes.Contains(e.Node))
     {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, e.Bounds);
         ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, Color.White, blueBrush.Color);
         e.Node.BackColor = blueBrush.Color;
         e.Node.ForeColor = Color.White;
      }
      else
      {
          e.Node.ForeColor = Color.Black;
          e.Node.BackColor = Color.Empty;
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you could include your custom drawing code, so far, so that potential answers have some context.  Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing the code for you here are a few pointers that might help:

- You can set `e.DrawDefault` to `false` to completely take control of the drawing process.
- Use the example in MSDN as a starting point (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawtreenodeeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
- If it were me, I'd just use these two unicode characters - `▼` and `►`, and draw them as text.

Comment: But my question is how to draw a node, which when selected looks like a button as shown in screenshot.

Comment: You can do that by adapting the code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawtreenodeeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx .  While sometimes code gets written for you in SO, sometimes you need to simply follow the advise given.